# ¿Cómo crear un script bash para actualizar multiples equipos a través de SSH?

Tags: bash, ssh, debian-9

Estoy intentando crear un script bash de linux en Debian 9 para que por medio de SSH al ejecutar el procese se actualicen los equipos de la red.

Esta es la manera como lo estaba pensando hacer:

```
sshpass -p "038dh4e" ssh -p 22 lgonzalez@192.168.0.12 "echo 038dh4e | sudo -S apt update;apt upgrade"

sshpass -p "893hehe" ssh -p 22 jhoyos@192.168.0.20 "echo 893hehe | sudo -S apt update;apt upgrade"
```

Pero estoy obteniendo el siguiente error, al ejecutar el script:

```
warning: apt does not have a stable cli interface. use with caution in scripts.
```

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Veo que intentas usar `apt update` dentro de un script, no es recomendable usarlo ya que apt arroja una barra de progreso y algunas cosas que no son facilmente manejables desde un script, te recomiendo cambiar `apt update` por `apt-get update`, tu script quedaría así:

```
sshpass -p "893hehe" ssh -p 22 jhoyos@192.168.0.20 "echo 893hehe | sudo -S apt-get update;apt-get upgrade"
```

Otra solución válida es enviar el output a un archivo `apt upgrade > /tmp/out.txt` y luego procesar el archivo si necesitas, el script quedaría así:

```
sshpass -p "893hehe" ssh -p 22 jhoyos@192.168.0.20 "echo 893hehe | sudo -S apt update >> /tmp/out.txt ;apt upgrade >> /tmp/out.txt"
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
#!/binbash
$DPATH=/home/user/script

while read -r values

    HOSTIP=$(echo $values | awk '{print $1}')
    USERNAME=$(echo $values | awk '{print $2}')
    PASSWORD=$(echo $values | awk '{print $3}')

    sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTIP "echo 893hehe | sudo -S apt-get update;apt-get upgrade" > /dev/null 2>&1

done <  $DPATH/credentials.txt
```

ahora el script `/home/user/script/credentials.txt` quedaria asi:

```
192.168.0.12 lgonzalez "038dh4e" 
192.168.0.20 jhoyos    "893hehe"
```

o la mejor forma seria creando una relacion de confianza entre los servidores con:

con los comandos:

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096 -t rsa
ssh-copy-id lgonzalez@192.168.0.12
ssh lgonzalez@192.168.0.12
```

con esto ya no pedira un password para conectarse a dicho servidor.

puedes seguir este [tutorial](https://blog.desdelinux.net/ssh-sin-password-solo-3-pasos/)

Comment: no hace falta hacer `while read` y luego coger los valores uno a uno con awk. Basta decir `while read -r var1 var2 var3`.